.NET 8.0 Project fails build Could not load System.Runtime - Reference Assemblies should not be loaded for execution
I have a project that is multi-targeting net8.0-windows and net48.  In both configurations it has no warnings or errors.  It builds fine in net48, but when I try to build the project in net8.0-windows I get this error:
1>Done building project "KeynoteManager.Core_4arjhlci_wpftmp.csproj".
1>LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)'
1>Done building project "KeynoteManager.Core.csproj" -- FAILED.

I have googled around about it and found some other similar things but nothing seems to work.
One item said to reference the offending dll as a nuget package.  However on NuGet System.Runtime doesn't have 4.2.2; I tried referencing 4.3.0 but no difference.
Some said they fixed it by just cleaning and deleting the bin folders.  I tried cleaning, deleting all bin and obj folders.  I tried restarting the machine.  I tried deleting and re-cloning the entire repo.  Nothing changes the result.
I do have one package that is a framework target so I thought that may be throwing issues, but I removed that package and all reference to it from my code and no change to the issue.
I have other projects that are set up exactly the same way as far as I can tell and they are building fine...
Help???
EDIT
I put in the lines before and after in the build output.  I noticed that for some reason it says it's done building a project that is mine but with a weird id in between with wpftmp in the name.  The last line is my actual csproj file name.  The other one I can't find any trace of on the system, so not sure where it's getting that to build or if it's generating it or what.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msbuild-is-adding-a-random-hash-and-wpftmp-to-my-a/210156

Holy crap you are a genius, THANK YOU!  That wasn't exactly the issue but it lead me to it.  I didn't have any unused namespaces, but in turning up the logging level and looking for the error it turns out it came processing .licx files.  I had an old one in there that wasn't even used anymore and that was causing an issue.  Deleted the file and it builds!

Make that an answer and I will accept it.

The thing that really helped from the comment on the original answer was to up the build verbosity to diagnostic and then search for the error.  That is what lead me to the answer so if you are seeing the same (which I think can happen from multiple issues) I would recommend doing that as a first step.  Here is the posted link that helped.
In my case specifically, I had an old .licx file in my project.  This was a license system from quite a while ago that was no longer valid but hadn't apparently been noticed or cleaned out in a while so it was still in the project.  Targeting .NET Framework 4.8 didn't have a problem with it but when I targeted .NET 8.0 it was causing an error and failed build.  I simply deleted that file and the error went away and it built successfully.
